# WebView и сохранение страниц

Tags: java, android

Добрый вечер господа. Подскажите пожалуйста есть ли метод в классе WebView для сохранения текущей просматриваемой web-страницы? Хочу реализовать возможность сохранения страниц и дальнейшего их просмотра без подключения к internet. Полистал документацию, ничего не нашел, возможно из-за невнимательности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью `WebView` — никак.

Можно просто скачать страницу в переменную, ну типа:

```
URL myUrl = new URL(url); //ссылка
InputStream inpstr = myUrl.openStream();
...
```

А потом сохранить ее в какой-нибудь файл.

И загружать в `WebView`:

```
WebView web = new WebView(myActivity);
String htmlPage = ...; //ваша сохраненная страница
String encoding = "utf-8"; //ваша кодировка страницы
web.loadData(htmlPage, "text/html", encoding);
```

Comment: спасибо, завтра изучу.

Comment: Ошибаетесь, можно из WebView достать HTML, и сохранить его. Примерно так: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20webview%20get%20html&es_th=1